# Facebook Messenger Chatbot not sending replies

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

```
function(resolve, reject) {
        request({
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/me/messages",
            qs: { 'access_token': process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
            method: "POST",
            json: {
                recipient: { id: recipientId },
                message: message
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            if(error) {
                console.log("Error sending message: " + response.error)
            } else {
                console.log("Message supposed to be sent: " + message)
                console.log(body)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

This is the function responsible for sending out messages.
It runs as a success when run. Triggering

```
console.log("Message supposed to be sent: " + message)
console.log(body)
```

Which then prints this out

```
Message supposed to be sent: sample text
{
  error: {
    message: '(#100) Message cannot be empty, must provide valid attachment or text',
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 100,
    error_subcode: 2018034,
    fbtrace_id: 'sometraceid'
  }
}
```

Is this my fault or meta's?

Answer (score 0):

```
      json: {
                recipient: { id: recipientId },
                message: message
            }
```

This part should be

```
      json: {
                recipient: { id: recipientId },
                message: { text: "your message"}
            }
```